# Busqueda por un campo en firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic

Tengo mi base de datos en firebase como la pueden observar aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El usuario escanea un producto y le trae el numero de este producto , el cual es puesto en un input , luego al darle click en buscar le **debe traer la descripcion y el valor de dicho elemento y mostrarlo en alguna parte del front**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como seria la función o query para que cuando la persona de click en buscar me traiga los datos solicitados ? se que es una consulta sencilla  pero no la tengo muy clara soy nuevo en ionic

Intente hacer esto para ver si me retornaba algo en la consola pero nada

```
findproduct(){
   var ref = firebase.database().ref("/productos/");
ref.orderByChild("Producto").equalTo(1706).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar otra estructura de datos.

Si usas:

```
{
"pructosbd": {
    "productos": {
        "7702158351852": {
            "descripcion": "...",
            "valor": "86.700.00",
            "id": "1"
        },
        "1706": {
            "descripcion": "...",
            "valor": "00.00",
            "id": "2"
        },
        "1137": {
            "descripcion": "...",
            "valor": "00.00",
            "id": "3"
        },
    }
}
```

}

No sé bien que fin cumple el campo `id` en tu estructura, si no es importante `producto` debería ser tu nuevo ID

Con la nueva structura puedes hacer una consulta de este tipo:

```
findproduct(){
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/productos/" + "1706").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

}

Por supuesto para que funcione el código del producto debería ser único. Al ser único solo necesitarás buscar en la ruta de tus productos, si el producto existe, tendrás toda la información disponible, en caso contrario la respuesta será nula.

Puedes encontrar información relacionada a este tema en: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data